# Assign value to pointer to pointer 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, allocation, calloc

I believe I have a declaration incorrect. I have an array that is 2D and an array that is 3D. I'm seg faulting because I'm assigning the value 0 -- or `NULL` to one of the arrays. I know this is trying to assign the address `NULL` to the pointer which is invalid.

Maybe I need to dereference the array before assigning? If so, how do I do this? If not, how do I need to declare the arrays?

```
double **WeightIH = calloc(51*20,sizeof(double **));
double ***Input = calloc(51*40, sizeof(double ***));
DeltaWeightIH[i][j] = 0.0 ;
```

Comment: Use `sizeof(*WeightIH)` instead, or always one star less than the pointer, in the first case `sizeof(double *)`. In this particular setup it doesn't matter, but if you had a pointer like `double *x;` `malloc()`ing `sizeof(double *)` would be wrong. Also, clarify your question, be specific. And don't use `***` triple star pointers. What do you need a "*3D array*" for?

Comment: You don't seemt o be declaring DeltaWeightIH - try double ***WeightIH = calloc(51*20, sizeof(double **)) since ** is as pointer to a pointer and *** is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer and **** is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @iharob I tried using `sizeof(*WeightIH)` and it still seg faults. I need a 3d array for a neural network

Comment: Handling a triple star pointer is very hard. It's not a good idea. You have to think of the model that correctly represents your data. For instance, you can have a `struct` with 3 pointers, each representing 1 dimension. It would be much easier to allocate, deallocate and handle it in general. The same applies to the `**` pointer. You really only need that if the elements of the array are *pointers* otherwise it's always wise to use a `struct` instead.

Comment: @Nunchy but I need `WeightIH` to be a 2d array. also I tried `sizeof(double *)` and it still seg faults

Comment: @iharob ah thank you! that's what I'll use

Comment: where's the rest of your code? you have to allocate each dimension when using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to define 5x6x7 matrix hope it helps.

```
float ***array3D;
array3D = malloc(5 * sizeof(float**));
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    array3D[i] = malloc(6 * sizeof(float*));
    for ( int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
         array3D[i][j] = calloc( 7, sizeof(float));
         for ( int k = 0; k < 7; ++k ) 
             array3D[i][j][k] = 1.0;  
    }
}
```

I wouldn't use calloc when define array of pointers since you filling them immediately in the same loop.
Don't forget to free, it will eat your memory very quick.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use for loops. just like the example below

```
int i, j = 0;
int rows = 5;
int cols = 2;

int rows2 = 3; // for 3d array

double  **arr2d = (double  **)calloc(rows, sizeof(double));
double  ***arr3d = (double  ***)calloc(rows, sizeof(double));
for (i = 0; i < rows; j++)
{
    arr2d[i] = (double *)calloc(cols, sizeof(double));
}

arr2d[1][2] = 0.0; //Or *(*(arr2d+1)+2) = 0.0;

//the same thing for 3d it just need another for loop.
for (i = 0; i < rows; j++)
{
    arr3d[i] = (double **)calloc(cols, sizeof(double));
    for (j = 0; i < cols; j++)
    {
        arr3d[i][j] = (double *)calloc(rows2, sizeof(double));
    }
}

arr3d[1][2][1] = 0.0; //Or *(*(*(arr2d+1)+2)+1) = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether a contiguous array would satisfy your requirements; but if it does then you can write more simply:

```
double (*a)[20] = malloc( 51 * sizeof *a );

double (*b)[20][30] = malloc( 10 * sizeof *b );
```

The innermost dimension goes on the right-hand-side, the other dimensions go on the left.

If you really do need a jagged array you need to write separate allocations for each row.